# Simple in-memory database

Tags: python, database, python-2.x

How can I improve this code (elegance, best practices, etc)?

```
""" Simple in-memory database as a response to the Thumbtack coding challenge. """


class SimpleDb(object):

    """ Simple in-memory database as a response to the Thumbtack coding challenge. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize SimpleDb instance. """
        self.__db = {}
        self.__num_equal_to_cache = {}
        self.__transactions = []  # Stores previous values to allow rollback

    def assign(self, name, value):
        """ Sets value of name to value. Inserts name into database if it doesn't already exist. """
        current_value = self.get(name)
        if current_value == value:
            return
        self.__update_num_equal_to(current_value, value)
        self.__update_current_transaction(name, current_value)
        self.__db[name] = value

    def get(self, name):
        """ Returns value of name if it exists in the database, otherwise returns None. """
        return self.__db[name] if name in self.__db else None

    def get_num_equal_to(self, value):
        """ Returns number of entries in the database that have the specified value. """
        return self.__num_equal_to_cache[value] if value in self.__num_equal_to_cache else 0

    def unset(self, name):
        """ Removes name from database if it's present. """
        current_value = self.__db.pop(name, None)
        if current_value is None:
            return
        self.__update_num_equal_to(current_value)
        self.__update_current_transaction(name, current_value)

    def begin(self):
        """ Opens transaction block. """
        self.__transactions += [{}]

    def rollback(self):
        """
        Reverts database to its state before most current transaction.
        Returns True on success, returns False if there aren't any open transactions.
        """
        if not self.__transactions:
            return False
        for name, value in self.__transactions.pop().iteritems():
            current_value = self.get(name)
            if current_value == value:
                continue
            self.__update_num_equal_to(current_value, value)
            if value is None:
                del self.__db[name]
            else:
                self.__db[name] = value
        return True

    def commit(self):
        """
        Commits all transactions to database. Returns True on success,
        returns False if there aren't any open transactions.
        """
        if not self.__transactions:
            return False
        self.__transactions = []
        return True

    def __update_num_equal_to(self, current_value, new_value=None):
        """
        Decrements by one the number items present with current_value (if current_value
        is not equal to None) and increments by one the number present with new_value
        (if new_value is not equal to None).
        """
        for amount_to_add, value in [(-1, current_value), (1, new_value)]:
            if value is not None:
                self.__num_equal_to_cache.setdefault(value, 0)
                self.__num_equal_to_cache[value] += amount_to_add

    def __update_current_transaction(self, name, value):
        """
        Stores current value of name if not already stored to most recent transaction
        (if any transactions open) to enable restoration of previous state on rollback.
        """
        if self.__transactions and name not in self.__transactions[-1]:
            self.__transactions[-1][name] = value


def display(value, default=None):
    """
    Prints value to stdout. If value is None and a default value is
    specified (and not None), then the default value is printed instead. Otherwise
    the None value is printed.
    """
    if value is None and default is not None:
        value = default
    print value


OPS = {
        'GET':        (2, lambda db, name:  display(db.get(name), "NULL")),
        'NUMEQUALTO': (2, lambda db, value: display(db.get_num_equal_to(value))),
        'UNSET':      (2, lambda db, name:  db.unset(name)),
        'BEGIN':      (1, lambda db:        db.begin()),
        'ROLLBACK':   (1, lambda db:        db.rollback() or display("NO TRANSACTION")),
        'COMMIT':     (1, lambda db:        db.commit() or display("NO TRANSACTION")),
        'END':        (1, lambda db:        False),
        'SET':        (3, lambda db, name, value: db.assign(name, value)),
}


def process_command(simpleDb, command):
    """
    Parses string commands and applies them to the database.
    Returning False indicates that no more commands should be passed in.
    """
    command = command.split()
    opcode = command.pop(0).upper() if len(command) > 0 else None
    if opcode is None or opcode not in OPS or len(command) != (OPS[opcode][0] - 1):
        print "INVALID COMMAND"
    elif 'END' == opcode:
        return False
    else:
        OPS[opcode][1](simpleDb, *command)
    return True


def run():
    """ Reads database command from the command line and passes it through for processing. """
    # BEGIN \n SET a 30 \n BEGIN \n SET a 40 \n COMMIT \n GET a \n ROLLBACK \n END
    simpleDb = SimpleDb()
    while process_command(simpleDb, raw_input()):
        pass

run()
```

Comment: Do you want to add http://www.thumbtack.com/challenges/software-engineer#simple-db to the question as a definition of the program's specification?

Comment: If you want to edit the code, put your edited code after (not replacing) the existing code; otherwise that invalidates existing answers: see [Can I edit my own question to include suggested changes from answers?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-suggested-changes-from-answers) for further details.

Answer (score 6):

I find your treatment of transactions odd.  I would expect that when a transaction is in progress, data modifications commands get buffered; queries would consult the state stored in the current transaction for any relevant data, then any stacked transactions, then finally consulting the "real" database.  Instead, you immediately "auto-commit" each command, and add an entry to the undo list; a commit simply discards the undo list.  That's not a realistic model of a database: one would expect that a commit either succeeds atomically or has no effect at all on the database.

Comment: I was thinking just that. I've re-written the code such that no changes are made until the user sends the commit command.

Comment: You might want to post the revised code as a second question, referencing this one.

Comment: some databases do indeed work like this -- optimistically committing, and writing a transaction log at the same time. it makes rollback more expensive, but commit much cheaper as you don't need to re-read the destination data to check that it's changed while the the transaction was running, before finally committing (and writing the rows). (eg: microsoft sql server works this way, as does oracle)

Comment: @AndrewHill No matter how the transaction is implemented, it should still be atomic.

Comment: yes, row/page locks in sql server and temp storage of old versions for rollback purposes in oracle both prevent partially complete transactions from becoming visible; these dbms's are atomic, they just rely on more sophisticated ; how should the database behave when when 2 transactions try to modify the same row / or read a row written but not commited?